# controlling whether a list have all element of a list that contains sets in python

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to write a function to find whether a list that contains sets are elements of another list. For instance:

`list1 =  [{'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c'}, {'d', 'a'}, {'c', 'b'}, {'d', 'c'}, {'e', 'c'}, {'e', 'd'}]`
and
`list2 = [{'a', 'c'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'b'}]`

as you can see, all elements of list2 can be found in list1. However, my code always produce false. How can I handle this problem? My code can be seen below.

```
check = all(item in list2 for item in list1)
print(check)
```

Comment: Your check is vice-versa.
you should swap ```item in list1 for item in list2```

Comment: thank you, I did not realize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check if all elements of list1 are in list2, which is not the case, therefore you get `False`.
I think you want to switch list1 and list2 in your check:

```
list1 =  [{'a', 'b'}, {'a', 'c'}, {'d', 'a'}, {'c', 'b'}, {'d', 'c'}, {'e', 'c'}, {'e', 'd'}]
list2 = [{'a', 'c'}, {'a', 'b'}, {'c', 'b'}]
check = all([item in list1 for item in list2])
print(check)
```

Result is `True`